# Laravel - Handling 500 error message

Tags: logging, laravel

In laravel I want to change the error message and log it for 404 and 500 event. i tried for 404 event by event listener in routes.php,

```
Event::listen('404', function()
{
Log::write('404', 'Could not find : '.URL::full());
return Response::error('404');
});
```

thats working fine for me. and error message is logged with the current url. but for 500 errors, I want to log stacktrace too.. i want the log message like "500 - Uncaught Exception:   'exception_message_and_stack_trace'"

how do I get the stacktrace string in event listener.. is it possible? sorry if I dont understand any basic things of laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 and 500 events doesn't have much information about the errors raised them, so you can't really do a stack trace there. They are basicly only for public messages for the users, who may hit something they shouldn't.

For logging you should use the logger closure in your config/error.php, fill the closure with your own logging logic, it has access to the exception object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sticky topic at Laravel Forums about Laravel Events. You may check the list [here](http://forums.laravel.com/viewtopic.php?id=3705).

Comment: thanks you for reply.. so 500 event listener dont have any arguments right..then is there any other way to tackle this. i just wanted to log the error message with stack trace

Comment: To listen Event:


    Event::listen('500', function($r)
    {
     dd($r);
     return Response::error('500');
    });

To Fire new Event:

    Event::fire(500, array('Uncaught Exception: exception_message_and_stack_trace'));

Answer (score 0):

Try adding code to application/config/error.php.  Enable logging by setting 'log' to true in that file.  Then at the bottom add a call to Log::write() like this:

```
    'logger' => function($exception)
    {
            Log::write('error', $exception);
            Log::exception($exception);
    },
```

This will make the exceptions show up in storage/logs/YYYY-MM-DD.log.   You could also have them written out to a database table, or have them emailed by making changes to this section.